# ¿como escribir en codigo python (py) el codigo kivy (.kv)?

Tags: python, kivy

Estoy empezando a utilizar kivy en phyton y deseo escribir todo en python para no estar saltando de un archivo a otro. He podido hacerlo en muchas ocaciones pero no puedo hacerlo en este caso

```
    **KIVI**

    GridLayout:
        id: container
        padding: [10,10,10,10]
        spacing: 5 
        size_hint_y: None
        col: 1
        row_default_height: root.height*0.2
        height: self.minimum_height

    **PYTHON**

    self.grid1=GridLayout(id= 'container',
                          padding= [10,10,10,10],
                          spacing= 5,
                          size_hint_y= None,
                          col= 1,
                          row_default_height= self.height*0.2,
                          height= self.minimum_height)
```

¿Donde puedo inetriorizarme para solucionarlo? Me dice que Las propiedades ['id'] pasadas a **init** no pueden ser nombres de propiedades existentes.
Me puden orientar en este tema. Muchas Gracias

Comment: Sería más fácil que te respondan si mostrás como lo estás implementando dentro de que clase, si ponés un ejemplo mínimo funcional se verá donde está el error.